# Is there anyway of opening html files directly at localhost on browser directly?

Tags: batch-file, automation

I know it sounds weird but what I want is to make some automation on machine. I want any html file would be opening from `.../htdocs/*` should open in browser with `http://localhost/*`. How would I achieve this ?

Problem is not that it is not loading but what I want is clicking on html file would be started on `localhost//...` path rather than `c://...` path.

I tried to search using batch job but I don't know how to code in it so I am trying to learn it though I'm not sure whether it serves my purpose or not.

Comment: for that don't you think you need a web server running on local system , to map to http://localhost:80

Comment: Yes. Please consider it as already started. Problem is not that it is not loading but what I want is clicking on html file would be started on localhost//... path rather than c://... path